# Can someone help me convert this paintings stamps & signature to American & give me an approximate value of this painting please? Thanks in advance

Tags: translation

I inherited this painting from my grandfather who bought this in China back I believe in the 70s or 80s. It is about 5 feet tall and about 2.5 feet wide  I am trying to determine the approximate value and translate the name and stamps of the artist. Can someone please help
[image: singature and stamps]

[image: Paintimg]

[image: stamps]

Comment: It can range from $0 to a million, depending on ..... :) Wrong place to ask this question.

Comment: Looking to convert name mostly.

Comment: The upper seal looks like "譚氏, and the bottom seal reads "華南". I guess "譚華南" is the person's name.

Comment: Can you convert that to English please?

Comment: 譚[tán] is his surname, 華南[Huánán] is a two-character given name, which means "south China". [pronounciation].

Answer (score 1):

"譚華南" is probably the artist's name. I see "甲辰" in the first photo, and this word belongs to a Chinese chronology, referring to 1964 (it's in a 60 year cycle, so it could be 1904 or 1844). I googled "譚華南" and found a Hong Kong artist with a same name(1941-1998), and he looks not famous because there's little information about him. Cant' help with appraisal.